# Xamarin Forms app lags on startup on T-Mobile only

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Has anyone experienced a lag on startup of Xamarin Forms iOS app when on T-Mobile cellular?  We have an app that starts up immediately when on WiFi or Verizon and AT&T cellular. But a device using T-Mobile cellular can take 60 to 90 seconds sitting on the main page and then suddenly populate. I can’t debug tethered either since tethering allows the app to start up fine also. If anyone has experienced this or can suggest some ideas I am open to them. Right now I have to implement NLog to get some debugging and timing issues to a file. Tedious to say the least.

Comment: Do you mean after launched page,there waiting for 60 to 90 seconds to show something?If mobile network signal or quality is not good, this may be possible.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you. I wanted to have a clear understanding of the loading process to be able to answer your question and while doing that leg work I actually discovered the issue. It was indeed an API call, but it wasn’t ours. We use a product called LiveXAML to help with UI development and it was left in the app since it didn’t seem to harm anything at the time. But on TMobile networks I noticed that it was trying to call home and kept trying for 60-90 seconds before it gave up and allowed the XAML to display.